# How can I write a nested Cargo.toml file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have an experimental Rust project that has the following directory structure:

[image]

My intention is to have the ability to build and run the mentioned binary executables from three directories independently.

As you can see there are three `Cargo.toml` files. #1 and #2 are functioning as intended. However, #3 is not. #3 is giving the following error;

```
C:\git\my_rust_workspace\my-numerical-package\my_bin>cargo build
error: current package believes it's in a workspace when it's not:
current:   C:\git\my_rust_workspace\my-numerical-package\my_bin\Cargo.toml
workspace: C:\git\my_rust_workspace\Cargo.toml

this may be fixable by adding `my-numerical-package\my_bin` to the `workspace.members` array of the manifest located at: C:\git\my_rust_workspace\Cargo.toml
Alternatively, to keep it out of the workspace, add the package to the `workspace.exclude` array, or add an empty `[workspace]` table to the package's manifest.

C:\git\my_rust_workspace\my-numerical-package\my_bin>
```

**How can I fix this?**

---

The content of #1 `Cargo.toml` file is:

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "my-numerical-package",
]

[package]
name = "my_rust_workspace"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
edition = "2021"
license = "Apache-2.0"
keywords = ["my_rust_workspace"]

[dependencies]
my-numerical-package = { path = "my-numerical-package" }
clap = { version = "3.1.18", features = ["derive"] }
rand = { version = "0.8.5", features = [ "small_rng" ] }
rand_distr="0.4.3"
nalgebra = "0.31.1"

# ---------- Logging
log = "0.4.0"
env_logger = "0.9.0"

[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "./main.rs"


[package.metadata.docs.rs]
# To build locally use
#   RUSTDOCFLAGS="--html-in-header katex-header.html" cargo doc --no-deps --document-private-items --open
rustdoc-args = ["--html-in-header", "katex-header.html"]
```

The content of #2 `Cargo.toml` file is:

```
[package]
name = "my-numerical-package"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "my_lib"
path = "./my_lib/lib.rs"

[[bin]] # my_rust_workspace/main.rs
name = "my_bin_1"
path = "../main.rs"

[[bin]]# my_rust_workspace/my-numerical-package/main.rs
name = "my_bin_2"
path = "./main.rs"

[[bin]]# my_rust_workspace/my-numerical-package/my_bin/main.rs
name = "my_bin_3"
path = "./my_bin/main.rs"

[dependencies]
rand="0.3.14"
rand_distr = "0.4"
```

The content of #3 `Cargo.toml` file is:

```
[package]
name = "my_bin_package"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "my_lib"
path = "../my_lib/lib.rs"

[[bin]] # my_rust_workspace/main.rs
name = "my_bin_1"
path = "../../../main.rs"

[[bin]]# my_rust_workspace/my-numerical-package/main.rs
name = "my_bin_2"
path = "../../main.rs"

[[bin]]# my_rust_workspace/my-numerical-package/my_bin/main.rs
name = "my_bin_3"
path = "./main.rs"

[dependencies]
rand="0.3.14"
rand_distr = "0.4"
```

Comment: Binaries don't get their own Cargo.toml. Only packages do.

Comment: That's not about feasibility, that's just how things are. They can't have their own Cargo.toml nor they need it.

Comment: I mean, it's not that you cannot do it (even though you cannot do it), it is just that putting its own Cargo.toml would be a meaningless act.

Comment: It is not doable, if that's the answer you want. But it's unclear to me what you would expect to gain from this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can still run them from any directory.

Comment: If you can run, then you can build, because you cannot run an unbuilt binary.

Comment: You just gotta add `my_numerical_package/my_bin/main.rs` as a `[[bin]]` to the workspace `Cargo.toml`. There's no need for a third manifest.

Comment: I don't see why this would be infeasible. I'm too lazy to try this right now, but shouldn't just adding `my-numerical-package\my_bin` to the #1 Cargo.toml `workspace.members` make the error go away? (Please add it as an answer if it works. And alternatively try adding a `[workspace] members = ["."]` to #3 Cargo.toml.) (I feel like the setup is rather nonsensical (I'd e.g. delete the `[lib]` from #3  Cargo.toml and instead add `[dependencies] my-numerical-package = { path = ".." }`).)